# calculating the remainder of a float and converting using javascript?

Tags: javascript, decimal

Say for instance a function that converts yards to miles in js is:

```
function yards_2_miles(num)
{
    return num *= 0.000568182;
}
```

and we want to convert 3000 yards:

```
var a = yards_to_miles(3000); // gives us 1.70455 miles
```

Now my problem is to calculate everything after the decimal point(remainder) to see if it amounts to a whole number in yards, in pseudo

```
if the remainder equals a whole number
   alert("1 mile 200 yards);
else
   alert(3.2 miles);
```

Im not sure if this is confusing, but i'm not good with maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of yards left over is the *modulus*, given by

```
yards % 1760
```

While the number of whole miles is the yards divided by (yards in a mile), as an integer:

```
parseInt(yards / 1760)
```

So you can write your function as

```
function yards_2_miles(num)
{
    var miles = parseInt(num / 1760);
    var yards = num % 1760;
    return miles + " miles and " + yards + " yards";
}
```

[Working example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamh/aHEF2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var miles = Math.floor(a);
var dec = a - miles;
var yards = dec / .000568182;
if(yards == Math.floor(yards)
    alert(miles + "miles " + yards + " yards");
else
    alert(a + " miles");
```

*EDIT*: Here, a more robust solution combines my original answer with adam's

```
function show_yards_to_miles(yards) {
    miles = Math.floor(yards / 1760);
    rem = yards % 1760;
    if(rem  == Math.floor(rem))
        alert(miles + " miles " + rem + " yards");
    else
        alert(yards / 1760 + " miles");
}
```

Comment: I don't think that works - if i put 3211 in the jsfiddle, I get `1.824432402 miles`

Comment: If it isn't exact yardage according to the conversion the OP gave, it will give it as a decimal.

Comment: Which is what the question asked for.

Comment: @adam That's probably round-off error. That's why using % is better. I was just trying to base my answer on the OP's code.

Comment: If you want the 1760 conversion, here is the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/pSc27/2/